# how to design a calendar control

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, calendar, custom-controls

I need to design a calendar control which should be added to our companie's application (I know there's already quite a lot calendar controls but I shall develop our own one...).

How should I start, should I use a kind of table to display the days or should I completely draw my own grid? How can I do this (I do not need rdy-to-use code, I just need some ideas...)

The application is written in C# as a WindowsForms application (thanks for the hint, forgot to mention this in first case...)

Comment: Why do you need to write your own?  Just curious

Comment: The first thing you'll have to do is decide on a technology. ASP.NET, WinForms, WPF and SilverLight are very different when it comes to control development.

Comment: Hmm, I'm sorry I forgot to mention that the technology decision is alread made. I'll modify my first post.

I need to develop an own one because it must be integrated in an already existant application, I need full access in means of style and functionality (--> no existing closed source project, no outlook plugin) and we must be able to choose a license which suits our needs (--> no existing open source project).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing your comment about WinForms and:

> I need to develop an own one because it must be integrated in an already existent application, I need full access in means of style and functionality

makes me suggest to use ready project http://www.codeproject.com/KB/selection/MonthCalendar.aspx and modify it if necessary. I use it in my own little project and it works like a charm. It provides full source if necessary so you can integrate it easily and modify if you think it's not `fit` enough.

In the end if you end up not using it, you can peak at the sources and functionality it implements and do it your own way.

To me redoing it from scratch is a bit pointless especially with such a good / free one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I'll at least have a look at this one. You're right, at least the code might give some ideas.

Comment: Well - I'll try this one now, maybe developing an own control is realy oversized ^^

Comment: Think so too :-) It really has a lot of functions and adding simple features (if necessary) is much easier then going for the big thing yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a web application then I would seriously look at using jquery. A good calendar control should be done client side so I would be looking at some form of java script solution. If you look at jquery-calendar.js as a good example you will see the complexity involved in developing your own control.

Comment: Well, as I'm developing WebApps by using QooxDoo JS Framework I would surely have chosen this framework for this project either. Thanks for your help but as I now specified I'm developing a C# Windows Forms application.

PS: have a look at qooxdoo (www.qooxdo.org) - great framework, great support.